# solidity program compiler issue

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
contract Greeter {
    string greeting;
    function Greeter(string _greeting) public{
        greeting=_greeting;
    }
    function greet() constant returns (string){
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'constant'
 --> project:/contracts/greeter.sol:7:22:
  |
7 |     function greet() constant returns (string){
```

i am compiling solidity program but  there is issue when compiling

Answer (score 0):

In the new compiler versions (*0.4.21 above*) the constructor and constant keyword deleted. Now, you must use for:

- **constructor**: the following statement for:

  `constructor([parameters]) {  // your logic }`
- **constant**: it depends on function accessibility that you give, in this case will be `external`. It allows to print the string that you initialized.

You must change your original smart in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Greeter {
    string greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() external view returns(string memory){
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use external or public instead of constant because constant keyword is deleted from solidity after version 0.4.21.